# Tizen web app - Embedding <video> inside <iframe> works in emulator, but not on the actual TV

Tags: reactjs, tizen, tizen-web-app

I have a simple Tizen webapp that works fine in emulator, but not on my Samsung signage TV (SSSP6).

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">   
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='embed-container'>
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-scripts allow-popups" src="https://ad-presenter-staging.herokuapp.com/betsonglobal"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I replace the `<iframe>` with an actual `<video>` with the same content as what's in src, then it works fine in both emulator and on the TV.

How do I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible URL is blocked during access. try updating the config.xml => policy => allow-navigation or Access
with external URL domain you want to access.

If I replace the  with an actual  with the same content as what's in src, then it works fine in both emulator and on the TV.
=> Does it show any error when  is used on TV? The info displayed in  region should be helpful to debug.

How do I go about debugging this?
=> If you're able to connect the TV to your PC, you can try launching the webapp in debug mode. After launch, if you check console section in Web Inspector, it should be logging the URLs blocked and the reason for block which should aid in fixing